# How to setup a new ruby2+rails4 environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

What should I notice, or say what's the different with setup a ruby 1.9 + rails 3 environment?

Answer (score 0):

No difference at all. However you installed Ruby 1.9, use it to install Ruby 2; and then `gem install rails -v 4.0.0rc1` as you normally would.

Comment: if there's one rc2 version months later, can I just modify that rc1 into rc2?

Comment: It would be good if you post the answer in complete, with `rvm` or `rbenv` guidelines. As I am also facing some issue in this installation. So if you have time please make the answer complete.

Comment: He asked how it was different from a Ruby 1.9/Rails 3 installation. I don't see how that requires a complete tutorial on installing Ruby. If he has 1.9, he knows how to install Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

***1.Install ruby 2.0.***

Make sure you have the latest RVM:

```
rvm get stable
```

For Debian-based systems

```
apt-get install libyaml-dev
```

For Fedora/CentOS/RHEL systems

```
yum install libyaml-devel
```

For Mac with Homebrew

```
brew install libyaml

rvm pkg install openssl

rvm install 2.0.0 \ 
    --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr \
    --verify-downloads 1

rvm use 2.0.0
```

***2.Install rails 4***

```
gem install rails -v 4.0.0rc1
```

Done.

Create new app by `rails new new_app`.

[Reference](https://coderwall.com/p/tptocq)

Comment: Good answer, but you need to give some more effort to your answer,as it is looking a bit crazy. Edit it properly :) :)

Comment: perfect,,, Here I go for *+1*. :)

Comment: You missed a whole lot of steps, like running `rvm requirements` and installing the long list of required packages.

Comment: No, do *not* `apt-get install rails`.

Answer (score 0):

I have blogged about the exact same topic. do check it out here: http://blog.parsalabs.com/blog/2013/08/27/setting-up-a-ruby-on-rails-4-development-environment-on-a-clean-mac-os-x-installation/

Hope it helps :)